# Set "content was updated"

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have such problem:

Site was totaly redesigned and everything works fine on my different devices (and even in different browsers). **But** some users (more than 3) can't load main page of the site (page is keep loading and users just see white page) - it's just stucks.

I think problem is somewhere around caching. Question is: how to tell browser that page was updated and it shouldn't load it from cache?

P.S. If URL is required - I'll post it here, but I'm not sure that it's legal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
?>
```

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Make sure this is before any data is sent to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options:

- you can set Cache Headers, that works most of the times (at least with current browsers). There is a lot to [read, e.g. this](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/).
- or you can append something that makes the URI unique every time the browsers asks. A timestamp works like a charm.

Example for the timestamp: if your URL is `http://www.example.com/some/thing/index.html`, then you can use `http://www.example.com/some/thing/index.html?ts=201401`